# how to write query or procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the two table once main table another once audit table for back up process if delete the record only on audit... if the record was deleted from audit means then update status on main table.....
for example table structure of **main** table

```
id name status
==============
1 raj    1
2 arivu  0
```

for example table structure of **audit** table

```
id name status
==============
1 raj    1
2 arivu  0
```

here the status 1 is active and 0 is inactive

if i **delete** the record from the **audit** table 
then output like
for example table structure of **audit** table

```
id name status
==============
1 raj    1
```

and
main table
for example table structure of audit table

```
id name status
==============
1 raj    1
2 arivu  2
```

if delete any record from audit table the record status is 0 or 1 just update it to 2

now i write procedure for solve the problem but i dont know how to call the procedure on php page
My Procedure is like

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `users` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `users`(in id int(25))
BEGIN

delete from person_history where id=id ;

update person set active='2' where id=id ;

END $$

DELIMITER ;

Comment: ..the best approach is to use a trigger on delete..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you **delete** the record from Audit table, Update the status in Main Table to 2 and then delete the record from Audit table. This will solve your problem.

So for example :

**Update:**

```
UPDATE main 
SET    status = 2 
WHERE  id not in (SELECT id FROM audit)
```

Comment: thank u so much.... but i need solution if the record was deleted then only i need to update main table...

Comment: you mean you want to update the table for already deleted records ?

Comment: yes... if the record already deleted from the audit table then update the main table

Comment: Do you have unique names ? what if there are two users with the same name ? how could you identify them in main table ?

Comment: in the both table the id was same....because audit table is the copy of the main table

Comment: i create the procedure for solve the problem but i dont know how to give the id

Comment: any one help for my new post

Comment: I have posted my answer.